# How can I access information in the selected row of a XAML gridview?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview

I have a listview with a gridview inside it and it is bound to a list of custom objects. In one cell I have three elements that I swap between, one of which is a hyperlink with a click event.

How do I get access to the 'CompanyName' that is bound in the same row when I go to the click event on the hyperlink?

This question may bely my ASP.Net background - I am very new to WPF.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="File" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CompanyFile}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Action" Width="300">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}" Visibility="{Binding Path=StatusVisibility}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=ButtonVisibility}"><Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_Click"><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Button}"></TextBlock></Hyperlink></TextBlock>
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Progress}" Visibility="{Binding Path=ProgressVisibility}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Hyperlink` inherits the `DataContext` of the parent `ListViewItem`, so you just need to cast it:

```cs
void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)sender;
    MyCustomObject obj = (MyCustomObject)link.DataContext;
    string companyName = obj.CompanyName;
    ...
}
```

Another option is to bind the hyperlink's `Command` property to a command on your `DataContext`, rather than handling the `Click` event explicitly. This helps decoupling the view from the business-related code, and it's the usual way of doing things in the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).